# C++ Writing simple coin flip game

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code for a game that prompts the user to pick how many times they want to flip a coin and guess how many times it will land on heads. I wrote most of, just need help finishing it up. I tried to include a count of the heads but ran into problems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int myRandNumGen(){

    int num = rand();

    return num;
}
char coinTossFunction( ){


    char coinToss;
    int coinTossValue = (myRandNumGen()%2); // 0 or 1

    switch (coinTossValue) {
        case 0:

            coinToss = 'H';

            break;

        case 1:

            coinToss = 'T';

            break;

        default:

            break;
        }
    return coinToss;
}

int calcCoin(int n){

    int cout_heads=0;

    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){

        if(coinTossFunction() == 'H')

            ++cout_heads;

    }

    return (cout_heads/n);

}




int main(){

    int coinflips, guess;

    cout << "How many times do you want to flip the coin? " << endl;
    cin >> coinflips;

    cout << "Guess how many times a coin will land on heads if flipped: " << endl;
    cin >> guess;
    if (guess>coinflips) {
        cout << "Guess Error";

    }


    for(int i=1;i<=coinflips;i++){
        cout << calcCoin;


    }
```

Comment: _"I wrote most of, just need help finishing it up"_ - exactly what problem are you having with it that needs _finishing up_?

Comment: You did not paste the full program. The bottom is missing. Maybe,  the problem lies there.

Comment: Thats all I have done. I'm confused on where to go from here. New to c++

Comment: That's pretty broad. You'll need to come up with a more specific question.

Comment: Okay, so pretty much my problem is the putting the count for the number of times the coin will land on heads. I attempted function calcCoin but I'm not confident in that and unsure how to use it in the int main() part of the code.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few problems with your code:

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
```

This will make `i` take the values from 0 to n, which means you will enter in the loop n+1 times, instead of n times.

```
return (cout_heads/n);
```

Since both variables `cout_heads`and `n` are integers, this will perform an integer division, and not a floating point division. The result will always be 0 or 1 in this case.

```
cout << calcCoin;
```

When you call a function you need to put parenthesis. Also your `calCoin` function takes a parameter.

Comment: what should I do to fix the for statement? Also on the calcCoin function, I think that I might be taking it out and using something else, I'm not too confident about using it

Comment: Doing the same thing that you did in your loop in main, if you iterate from 1 to n you will enter the loop n times exactly.

Comment: okay, I have another question. How do I get the program to end if there is a guess error? I dont want it to follow through with the rest of the code

Comment: Indeed. You can use `return 1;` to exit the main function (and thus exit the program). The returned value of main tells whether the application was successful or not (0 means no error, 1 means error).